# Noob question pyspark - get all columns with min/max salary

Tags: pyspark, min

I'm new to pyspark and understand the various aggregate functions. However, they give only the column where the aggregate function is applied. For example, if my dataframe df is -

`Employee|Age`

`ABC|23`

`XYZ|32`

The result derived by `df.select(min("Age")).show()` -

`min(Age)` - 23

I'm looking to get this -

`Employee|Age`

`ABC|23`

Answer (score 0):

Use join.

```
df_data = [
    ('abc',23),
    ('def',32)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_data, ['Employee', 'Age'])

df_min_age = df.groupBy().agg(min('Age').alias('Age'))
df_min = df.join(df_min_age, ['Age'], 'inner')

df_min.show()

+---+--------+
|Age|Employee|
+---+--------+
| 23|     abc|
+---+--------+
```